# Discord.py Program Ends Instantly

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am trying to program a Discord bot in Python using the `discord.py` module.

When I run the code, it doesn't say anything, waits a little (probably importing/connecting stuff) and then closes - or in IDLE, `>>` appears.

There is no problem with the code, as it doesn't give any errors. Plus, if I run a command out of `on_ready()` it works as expected.

So the problem isn't because of not being able to connect to the bot or Discord, is it? Perhaps the `asnyc` function doesn't work, or the interpreter doesn't recognize it?

Here is the basic form of the main code:

```py
    import discord
    
    token = 'blahblah'
    
    client = discord.Client()
    
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
           if message.content=="some input":
                  msg = 'some output'
                  await message.channel.send(msg)
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
           print("All works fine!")
    
    client.run(token)
```

Comment: I am not having the problem of the bot failing to start. Silly question, but is your bot actually in a server? How much RAM do you have? What versions of discord.py/python are you using?

Comment: 1- Yes, I already added it to my test server. 2- What should be the lowest RAM for it to work? 3- 3.8.5 (Python) - Guess 1.0.1 (Discord.py)

Comment: I don't know if this issue is necessarily version related, but you should definitely update to the last version just in case. Lot of fixes can happen between 1.0.1 and 1.5.0. Also, I don't know but at least 2gb of RAM should be fine. My VM uses 2gb of ram and my test bot runs fine. That's probably not the issue.

Comment: @Allister That was night here and you answered right after I closed the computer :D, Then I saw your reply via phone but I wasn't logged in there, I thought of replying back morning, but I eventually forgot it.. Apologizes... And yes, I'll try uprading. Do we do it in cmd or download something?

Comment: If you have Pip installed (which comes automatically with Python) you should just be able to use cmd to `pip install discord.py`, which will get the latest version.

Comment: @Allister Is it the latest version if it says "Requirement already satisfied" or is it just something going on in there?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied means you have the package but not necessarily the right version as I understand it. I gave you the wrong command. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071256/how-to-update-upgrade-a-package-using-pip Do `pip show discord.py` to see if it worked.

Comment: @Allister Yes, it works. Thank you very much! Now it is 1.5.0 -as you mentioned in one of your older comments.  Sometimes there are little problems where you know if you change a little thing, but you can't find that thing. Have a nice day! :) EDIT: That guy in the link you gave had th same problem but I couldn't notice it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention something about it being an issue with async I shall leave an answer that I gave another user about async. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63005581/13950887

Another issue ***I*** had recently was due to discord updating their website from discordapp.com and discord.gg to discord.com, a way I found to resolve this was to edit a bunch of the files, one thing I will say is that I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It was a problem about the version of Discord.py. It works now.